# Storing a dynamic collection of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to improve the way I code actively-changing Javascript/jQuery devices. One thing I do to streamline the code is to store collections of elements in jQuery objects like so:

```
var links = $('a');
```

This saves me processing time by not having to constantly recreate that jQuery object. I then run code that affects the appearance of those elements:

```
links.css('color', '#ff0000');
```

The thing is, other parts of my script create new links to add to that collection, that I sequentially want to alter. But if I try to do anything to that collection, it of course will only affect that original set:

```
links.css('color', '#ffff00');
```

So my question is: Is there a way to create a jQuery collection of elements that changes as you add more to the markup, with redefining the collection?

Comment: No. Instead, you could have a custom event that gets triggered on the document (or some other element, or maybe even just a function that you call) that you can listen for. when said event happens, re-populate the collection.

Comment: In this case, you can use `$(document.links).dostuff()` assuming all your anchor tags contain href attributes.

Comment: It depends on the selector. If you select by tag only, `document.getElementsByTagName` would return a live node collection. But there is no such thing for the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The htmlcollections returned by getElementsByTagName and the getElementsByClassName functions of document keep updating themself on any update in the dom.

```
var htmlcollection = document.getElementsByTagName('a);
console.log(htmlcollection.length); // returns 0;

$('body').append("<a/>");
console.log(htmlcollection.length); //returns 1;
```

You could use $(htmlcollection) each time. I think it would be more efficient as you are already providing the elements to jquery. And these elements need not be searched on the dom each time.

Comment: FWIW, the value returned by those functions is not an array. It's a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`. These are *array-like* objects.

Comment: Is it possible to use the getElementsByTagName collection like an array and loop through it like any jQuery object?

for instance:
`var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
$.each(links, function(){ $(this).doSomething(); });`

Comment: yes as mentioned by Felix Kling it is quite similar to an array so you can easily use a loop over it and also you can always use it as $(htmlcollection).each to loop through it.

Comment: I'm very new to getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName (I learned jQuery before basic Javascript functions). How would I use to select a specific instance of a tag or class? For instance, would `var links = getElementsByClassName('#product-content .product-rows .link');` work?

Comment: getElementsByClassName accepts only class and getElementsByTagName accepts only tags. For your purpose, you need to use, document.querySelectorAll('#product-content .product-rows .link'); it works similar to jquery selectors. Only that this also updates itself on dom update.